# SOAP Webservice is giving the below error

Tags: java, soap

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.

Tried Generating certificate using http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/, but still getting the exception

Comment: Did you do _Step 3. Verify Trusted Keystore_? What was the result?

Comment: Yes we did that, but still same error